# Getting JSON From An External MySQL Database Error?

Tags: php, json

i am using this tutorial and i dont know what is error is this

```
    <?php
header('Content-type: application/json');  // this is the magic that sets responseJSON

// Connecting, selecting database
$link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)
    or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die('Could not select database');

switch($_POST['op']) {
    case 'getAllRecords': {
        $table = $_POST['table'];
        $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s", mysql_real_escape_string($table));
        // Performing SQL query
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
        $all_recs = array();
        while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $all_recs[] = $line;
        }
        break;
    }
}

echo json_encode($all_recs);

// Free resultset
mysql_free_result($result);

// Closing connection
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

error is :- null
**Warning**:  mysql_free_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in **/home/ajay/public_html/mapleleafrealities.com/test.php** on line **26**

[This is Example](http://www.webos-internals.org/wiki/Tutorials_webOS_Getting_JSON_From_An_External_MySQL_Database)

[My Error](http://mapleleafrealities.com/test.php)

if you have any simple example of getting json from external db please give me link or code

Comment: http://www.webos-internals.org/wiki/Tutorials_webOS_Getting_JSON_From_An_External_MySQL_Database check out this link and explain me according to this

Comment: So you don't know anything about PHP. This is Worthless to explain anything to you. You should go with some tutorial first to learn PHP.

Comment: i think Shakti still do not get my problem its for a WebOs, please first understand that what a guy asking it doesn't matter he/she is beginner or expert

Comment: What are you asking is self-explanatory to me. It does matter because if you see below two answer they are explanatory enough. But you are not getting what they are asking for that's why you posted your first comment.

Comment: the link that you have posted is explaining everything go with that. Don't waste your value able time here with this question

Answer (score 1):

The `op` POST parameter is not "getAllRecords", so you're trying to encode something that doesn't exist, and free a result that was never taken. Try putting them inside.